# app freezes In facebook login in Windows Phone devices

Tags: facebook, windows-phone

I have integrated Facebook in my app. I am using webbrowser to authenticate user on facebook and we are using facebook api to acess user facebook credentials.

If we enable the secure browsing and Login Notifications in Facebook->settings->Privacy Settings->Security

then we are getting the facebook freeze problem after login.

and if we disable the above( secure browsing and Login Notifications ) setting then app is fine.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **IsScriptEnabled="true"** on the WebBrowser you use to authenticate the user. That should do it.

I had similar problems with Facebook lately and it was because of that.